# Playwright-Getting text from locator element

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to grab just the order number in the h1

```
<h1 class="FulfillmentHeaderstyles__FulfillmentHeaderTitle-sc-1ges29w-3 PjsJX">
   Order #1004066
   <div aria-label="promise time" class="FulfillmentHeaderstyles__FulfillmentPromiseTime-sc-1ges29w-7 elUWJn">7:09 PM</div>
</h1>
```

Code tried

```
const orderNumber = await window.locator('[class*=FulfillmentHeaderTitle]').textContent();
console.log(orderNumber);
```

> Console log result: Order #10040657:09 PM

How can I grab just the order number "Order #1004065" and not the child.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the textContent keeps new lines, you could split the string on that? `orderNumber.split('\n').at(1) // "   Order #1004066"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('h1').innerText.split('\n')[0])
```

```html
<h1 class="FulfillmentHeaderstyles__FulfillmentHeaderTitle-sc-1ges29w-3 PjsJX">
   Order #1004066
   <div aria-label="promise time" class="FulfillmentHeaderstyles__FulfillmentPromiseTime-sc-1ges29w-7 elUWJn">7:09 PM</div>
</h1>
```

Here you get the `innerText` and then split it at the line break to get an array, which looks like `['Order #1004066', '7:09 PM']`. So, you take the first element at index 0 to get the order number.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
const orderNumber = await window.locator('[class*=FulfillmentHeaderTitle]').innerText();
```